# Request method PUT was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods list

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, cross-domain

I am working with CodeIgniter Rest server, I am making PUT request . Everything works fine in the chrome and firefox, but in the internet explorer I keep getting an error saying **Request method PUT was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods list.**, i even added the response headers to allow the different methods , following is the rest service

```
public function service_put()
{
    if (!$this->_allow) return;

    $data = $this->_put_args;

    if(isset($data))
    {
       // have my arguments

        try{

             header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
             header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,PUT,GET,DELETE');
             header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type, Accept');

             $this->response(['done' => TRUE], REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); // (200) HTTP response code

        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
             $this->response(array('error' => $e->getMessage()), $e->getCode());
        }

        return;
    }
    else
    {
         $this->returnBadRequest();
        return;
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting spaces in the allowed methods after the comma?

Comment: Hi I saw that my rest controller is appending spaces to the request methods, so I removed them , it works fine now